# How do I render over a tracked image on Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

I'd like the Hololens to take in through the camera and project an image over tracked images and I can't seem to find a concrete way as to how online. I'd like to avoid using Vuforia etc for this.

I'm currently using AR Foundation Tracked Image manager (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/manual/tracked-image-manager.html) in order to achieve the same functionality on mobile, however it doesn't seem to work very well on hololens.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AR Foundation is a Unity tool and 2D Image tracking feature of AR Foundation is not supported on HoloLens platforms for now, you can refer to this link to learn more about feature support per platform:[Platform Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/index.html#platform-support)

Currently, Microsoft does not provide an official library to support image tracking for Hololens. But that sort of thing is possible with OpenCV, you can implement it yourself, or refer to some third-party libraries.

Besides, if you are using HoloLens2 and making the QR code as a tracking image is an acceptable option in your project, recommand using [Microsoft.MixedReality.QR](https://www.nuget.org/Packages/Microsoft.MixedReality.QR) to detect an QR code in the environment and get the coordinate system for the QR code, more information please see: [QR code tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/qr-code-tracking#getting-the-coordinate-system-for-a-qr-code)